# Add virtual X11 screen to use via VNC

Tags: 14.04, gnome, xorg, multiple-monitors, vnc

I'm trying to add a second screen to my ubuntu 14.04 gnome setup, via a VNC client. To be clear: I don't want to connect to a different session, but the same. However, I want to see a different screen, not mirror the existing physical screen. I just want to extend the existing display with a "virtual" second screen that I can reach through VNC, instead of a physical one.

Much to my dismay, I haven't found a way to achieve this, let alone a simple one. Is there a way at all?

The VNC client will be an iPad app in this case, but it could be anything with a VNC client really, such as an old laptop that I wanted to use as a second monitor.

This might be a duplicate of ["Adding a virtual screen to xorg.conf 11.04 (third display over vnc)"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65928/adding-a-virtual-screen-to-xorg-conf-11-04-third-display-over-vnc). However, there is no answer to the actual question, and an answer suggesting a different route is accepted, so I'm posting this one to try and find an actual solution.

Comment: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=191555 That seems to be your  solution. Didn't try, but looks good.

Comment: did it actually 'work' good when you tried? (if you did try?)

Comment: @Rexford it worked well, but not fast enough to watch a video or drag files around. VNC is really slow for those use cases. I usually just put a terminal window on the iPad screen and do everything else on the main display.

Comment: @AntonioFeitosa This question is not a duplicate  of "How do you use an android tablet as a second display?" or of any other question that I could find when I searched for another duplicate question.

Comment: I made a simple bash script to make a tablet a second display. Copy `ipad_monitor.sh` (Don't worry. it also works with any VNC clients) from my [blog post](https://kbumsik.io/using-ipad-as-a-2nd-monitor-on-linux.html).

Comment: @BumsikKim that's great! I have a script of my own now (I had forgotten about this question). But yours is tidier, you should post an extract of your blog post as an answer :)

Comment: How about the answers in https://askubuntu.com/q/453109/26246

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`virtscreen` on linux to use an ipad or other computer as a secondary screen](https://github.com/kbumsik/VirtScreen).

```
sudo apt-get install x11vnc
wget https://github.com/kbumsik/VirtScreen/releases/download/0.3.1/virtscreen.deb
sudo dpkg -i virtscreen.deb
virtscreen
```

The app is made by [Bumsik Kim](https://askubuntu.com/users/447956/bumsik-kim) who commented above (but it's been a year and they've not posted their solution, so I did).