# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS remote desktop legacy VNC only accept one connection

Tags: gnome, 22.04, vnc

As the title stated, I enabled ubuntu gnome default screen share service. The good thing is it supports both MS RDP and VNC protocols. However I find the VNC only accepts one connection. If one user is already VNCed to the desktop, 2nd user (using realVNC) will only get an error "The connection closed unexpectedly". Another good thing is the RDP connection does not have this restriction. Several users can RDPed to the same desktop simultaneously(which is also wired since the real MS windows DESKTOP edition only accepts one connection).
In /var/log/syslog there's an log event "gnome-remote-de[process id]: Refusing new VNC connection: already an active session"

Anybody knows how to make multiple VNC connections? Surely I can use RDP, but I'd stick with VNC since other computers works fine with VNC. Using more than one tool seems...annoying.
Installing another VNC server seems an overkill.

amend:
I just noticed the desktop is X11 not wayland. Delete all "wayland" above.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to define more displays in your X11config for vnc. It currently only has one physical attached display. I have not done this kind of thing therefore I do not know how to do it. Google is your friend: [Add virtual X11 screen to use via VNC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617815/add-virtual-x11-screen-to-use-via-vnc)